# Forward Iterator C++ : for_each behavior

Tags: c++, foreach, iterator, forward

So we know that foreach is something like :

```
template<class InputIterator, class Function>
  Function for_each(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Function f)
  {
    for ( ; first!=last; ++first ) f(*first);
    return f;
  }
```

I have implemented a

```
template <typename T>
class Range
```

The problem is that when I use this function with the for_Each :

```
static void add1(float &v)
{
  ++v;
}
```

it go in infinite loop because of first "!=" last (it's not first"<"last), so how people do when they implemente their own forward iterator to work with for_each ?

Comment: Show us how are you implementing the `iterator` class... Does it work if you replace `for_each` with a regular `for` loop? I guess not, otherwise you wouldn't be blaming `for_each`.

Comment: How did you implement equality/inequality comparisons for your iterator?

Comment: Ok I edited the first post @K-ballo

Comment: With comparaison of the data private member pData_ @dirkgently

Comment: Is `pData_` pressumably an integral type?

Comment: @K-ballo : Yes for sure.

Comment: `float` is **NOT** an integral type. Floats and exact comparisons are troublesome because of inexact representation and rounding errors. Could you try replacing `float` with `int` and see how that works?

Comment: Didn't even see the float there XD

Comment: @chris : I tried with int and it's the same, inside the for_each it goes : 1
3
5
7
9
11

Comment: So there seems there is something wrong with your iterator's increment operator, right?

Comment: @K-ballo : no, what do you have in mind ?

Comment: Either your increment operator is doing +=2 instead of +=1, or your initial range is invalid.

Comment: @K-ballo : Like you see in my code, I don't +=2 and my range is just 1 to 6... so I don't understand.

Comment: If your increment operator is jumping +=2 then you are likely to overjump end iterator so != obviously doesn't work. If this is fuctionality you desire (I mean +2 jumps) then error is in incorrect end iterator value - it should be adjusted to correct any odd element.

Comment: @j_kubik : But why are you saying that ? You see my increment operator is my first post, i don't jump +=2...

Comment: @Bebeoix sorry, I misunderstood you. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem of your approach is that your iterator increment operators do not change the iterator, but rather the stored value. This means that inside the `for_each` loop, the condition is modified both in the increment operator of the iterator and also through the function.

Comment: Hum I think I see what you mean, so what solution do you propose ?

Comment: @Bebeoix. The issue here is that you have not actually asked how to solve any particular problem, but rather asked about your proposed solution. The first thing that comes to mind is that the iterator in a *range* (understood as values), should not be a `ForwardIterator`, but rather an `InputIterator`, which would solve your issue (by making the use of that iterator with that `add` function in `std::for_each` illegal)

Comment: Yes but it says here "http://cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/" that if we manage forward iterator it should be ok to use algorithm who need input iterator right?

Comment: @Bebeoix: The link is broken (the linked page does not work). If what you are trying to say is that by providing a `ForwardIterator` you can use a function that takes an `InputIterator`, that is correct. But the problem is that for a range of numbers you do not *want* to provide a *mutable iterator* (C++11 parlance) because modifications to the `value_type` will modify your *iterator*. Note that the actual issue here is not `InputIterator` vs. `ForwardIterator`, but rather *mutable iterator* vs. non-mutable iterators.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve anyway... does your class have any internal storage at all, or is it only represenatation of number sequence?

If so, then the problem are operators `T &operator*()` and `T *operator->()` which allow value pointed to by iterator to be changed. But if it's only range class it obviously cannot be edited this way, and you should rather use `cons_iterator`.

If your class have an internal storage then your interator should have pointer to it (`T* pData_;` instead of `T pData_;`) and then you dont need to remove star in `T &operator*()`
 which suprisingly was ready for correct version ;) The point is that incrementivg iterator should increment this pointer and incrementing value in your `add1` function should increment pointed value. Now both operations increment the same variable, so you get those `+=2`.

EDIT:

@DavidRodríguez-dribeas - You are considering different input iterator categories, which are meant to describe the difference between allowed sequential access (in what sequence elements can be accessed), but described problem is rather that `Range` class instances are by design constant (at least not possible to be modified using just iterators). I can't see anything against giving it even random access category.

The only option is to replace iterator with const_iterator everywhere, so that iterated values cannot be modified. Now this is a bit against ISO C++, which divides containers into several categories and for each category it requires `begin()` and `end()` to return `const_iterator` only if container itself is declared `const`. However I think it is arguable at most that `Range` class is even container in ISO C++ view, as (according to 23.1.1)

> Containers are objects that store other objects. They control
>   allocation and deallocation of these objects through constructors,
>   destructors, insert and erase operations.

Sice there seem not to be any actual storage of iterated objects in Range class, I think we are out-in-the-wild here, and don't need to comply with standard that much.

EDIT2:

Firstly `const iterator` is NOT the same as `const_iterator`. The first one is an iterator that cannot be changed (to point to a different value in sequence eg. incremented), and another one allows that, but instead doesn't allow changing pointed value, so `(*i)=3` would fail.

Secondly this is how I would have done it:

```
template <typename T>
class Range {
public: 
    class const_iterator;
    typedef const_iterator iterator; //For stl-compliance - some algorythms use that.

    IntegerRange(T low, T high) : low_(low), high_(high) { assert(low <= high);}
    const_iterator begin() const { return const_iterator(low_); }
    const_iterator end() const { return const_iterator(high_); }
private:
    const T low_;
    const T high_;
};

template<typename T>
class Range<T>::const_iterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, T>
{
public:

 // default constructor                                                                         
  const_iterator() : pData_(0)
  {
  }

  // constructor from const T&                                                                   
  const_iterator(const T &pData) : pData_(pData)
  {
  }

  // constructor from T&                                                                         
  const_iterator(T &pData) : pData_(pData)
  {
  }

  // operator =                                                                                  
  const_iterator &operator=(const const_iterator &other)
  {
    this->pData_ = other.pData_;
    return *this;
  }


  // pre-increment operator                                                                      
  const_iterator & operator++()
  {
    ++(this->pData_);
    return *this;
  }
  // post-increment operator                                                                     
  const_iterator operator++(int)
  {
    const_iterator temp(*this);
    this->operator++();
    return temp;
  }

  // operator ==                                                                                 
  bool operator==(const const_iterator &other) const
  {
    return this->pData_ == other.pData_;
  }

  // operator !=                                                                                 
  bool operator!=(const iterator &other) const
  {
    return !operator==(other);
  }

  // operator* r-value                                                                           
  const T &operator*() const
  {
    return (this->pData_); // had to remove the *                                                
  }

  // operator-> r-value                                                                          
  const T *operator->() const
  {
    return &(this->pData_);
  }

private:
  T pData_;
};
```

You are obviously free to keep the name iterator instead of const_iterator (or use qqwfmnghng as class name) as long as you do keep to const_iterator specification - in this case not providing l-value operators, as those are intended to modify pointed value - what sense would that make?

Comment: [Edit:I edit the first post to add the whole class Range] Ok thanks I see what you mean, this si my whole class Range :
`
template <typename T>
class Range
{
public:
  class iterator;

  IntegerRange(T low, T high) : low_(low), high_(high)
  {
    assert(low <= high);
  }

  const iterator begin() const
  {
    return iterator(low_);
  }

  const iterator end() const
  {
    return iterator(high_);
  }

private:
  const T low_;
  const T high_;
};
`
So I have to pass &low_ and &high_ if I follow you ?

Comment: But I can't change the class Range, I should just change Range::iterator.

Comment: What is your `add1` function doing - is it supposed to modify anything (iterator? range?) currently it is changing the value stored in iterator (and thus modyfing iterator). You realy shouldn't return non-const referene or pointer to internal iterator field. You should use const_iterator (that doesn't have `T &operator*()` and `T *operator->()`) to disallow modyfying values in `Range` class as it makes no sense.

Comment: *Now this is a bit against ISO C++, which divides containers into several categories and for each category it requires begin() and end() to return const_iterator only if container itself is declared const.* Not really true, the example is `std::set`, neither `iterator` nor `const_iterator` allow the modification of the referenced element, the difference between the two is whether they can be used to remove the element back from the `std::set`.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas - true, and I think his class is conceptually similar to set anyway (set of numbers between begin and and). Anyway bottom line is that his iterator, however defined should not allow element modification.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <assert.h>     // assert
#include <iterator>     // std::forward_iterator
#include <utility>      // std::pair
#include <stddef.h>     // ptrdiff_t, size_t

typedef size_t          UnsignedSize;
typedef ptrdiff_t       Size;
typedef Size            Index;

template< class TpValue >
class ValueRange
{
public:
    typedef TpValue     Value;

private:
    Value   first_;
    Size    span_;

public:
    class It
        : public std::iterator< std::forward_iterator_tag, Value >
    {
    friend class ValueRange;
    private:
        Value       first_;
        Index       i_;

        It( Value const first, Index const i )
            : first_( first )
            , i_( i )
        {}

    public:
        void operator++()           { ++i_; }
        Value operator*() const     { return first_ + i_; }

        bool operator!=( It const& other ) const
        { assert( first_ == other.first_ );  return (i_ != other.i_); }

        bool operator<( It const& other ) const
        { assert( first_ == other.first_ );  return (i_ < other.i_); }
    };

    Value first() const     { return first_; }
    Value last() const      { return first_ + span_; }

    It begin() const        { return It( first_, 0 ); }
    It end() const          { return It( first_, span_ + 1 ); }

    ValueRange( Value const first, Value const last )
        : first_( first )
        , span_( Size( last - first ) )
    {
        assert( first_ + span_ == last );
    }
};

#include <algorithm>    // std::for_each
#include <iostream>     // std::wcout, std::endl

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    ValueRange< double > const   r( 1.0, 6.0 );

    for_each( r.begin(), r.end(), []( double x )
    {
        using std::wcout;       // For Visual C++ 10.0.
        wcout << x << " ";
    } );
    wcout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Very good/clear/nice solution. (forward_iterator doesn't need to have operator < though, and it need the operator ->)

Comment: @Bebeoix: just add what you need, when you need it.