# C++ Range of integer class - kind of Iterator to choose

Tags: c++, iterator, forward

This is the Range class :

```
template <typename T>
class Range
{
public:
  class iterator;

  Range(T low, T high) : low_(low), high_(high)
  {
  }

  const iterator begin() const
  {
    return iterator(low_);
  }

  const iterator end() const
  {
    return iterator(high_);
  }

};
```

Which king of iterator (forward, random, input) is the best to choose ?

Comment: Your end iterator should be `high_ + 1` (one past the end). Random is the best way to go in your case.

Comment: I don't think so because of it should be [low,high)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide any type of iterator, including if you wish a random iterator, as long as you do not allow modification of the iterator state from `operator*` or `operator->`. That is, if you are keeping the count in the iterator, then `operator*` should return a `T` (value) and `operator->` a `T const *`, so that the iteration cannot be modified through these operators.

Answer (score 0):

@K-ballo is right, random is the best way, depends on algorithm though. Could you, please, describe them as well?

Comment: Ok but seriously I have no idea how to manage the problem that I had in my previous version (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770489/forward-iterator-c-for-each-behavior)

Comment: How should the sequence look like, after execution of for_each(begin(), end(), ++v) for range 1..6?

Comment: The only normal way : [2..6] because [1..6)

Comment: And the second question, why should it really work with only one copy of data. David Rodrigues in the previous post way right with the consideration, that it's incorrect to change the data twice.

Comment: And if, for example for_each(begin(), end(), v*=2) will be called?
For ++v version I see the following cheat code: implement for_each in the following way:
`{
  f(*first);
  f(*last);
}`

Comment: Imagine that you have the class Range<T>, just tell me the solution to implement the class Range<T>::iterator , assuming that T will always be an integer (signed or unsigned). Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but iterators are designed to work with object located in memory. In your case, I'd prefererred to override for_each implemenation with partial template specification.
On the other hand, you could create temporary in memory values, using for example an underlying vector.